# Count registered users by province or state Geocoder RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-geocoder

Is there any way to count users based on their province or state (Canada or US) with `devise` and `geocoder`? Tried to google but haven't found a solution.

`user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable


  # attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }


  # Mandatory fields
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_presence_of :business_name


end
```

Example of what I want to get:
- Ontario: 89
- California: 32
- Quebec: 382
- etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a native way to do that. Implement methods to do what you want:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # your stuff...
    def city
      lat_lon = "#{latitude},#{longitude}"
      Geocoder.search(lat_lon).first
    end

    def self.grouped_by_city
      group_by{ |user| user.city }.map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}.to_h
    end
end
```

Then you can call:

```
 User.all.grouped_by_city
 User.where(some_finder: some_value).grouped_by_city
```